# save_post() on Menu Save

Tags: menus, save-post

When the wordpress menu is saved in the backend, functions hooked on to save_post() run. Is there a way to make these run only when singular items are saved, and not when the menu is saved?

Comment: Sorry but i am not getting you, What exactly you want !!

Comment: Menus are singular items. Technically. Inside your function you should be checking what kind of post is being saved, and that any data you're expecting exists. If you have code that's causing you trouble, you'll need to share it to get any help.

Comment: each menu item is a custom post type, you should be checking the post type of the post when the `save_post` hook runs. Don't assume it only runs for `post`, it runs for pages, nav menu items, reusable blocks, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mr. Peattie and Mr. Nowell pointed out, you should check the post type as one of the first things in your [`save_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) function.

Here's couple of ways how to do it,

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'prefix_my_save_post_action', 10, 3 );
function prefix_my_save_post_action( $post_id, $post, $update ) {

  // Check for single post type
  if ( 'my_post_type' !== $post->post_type ) {
    return;
  }

  // Check multiple post types with in_array()
  $valid_post_types = array(
    'post' => true,
    'page' => true,
    'post_type_a' => true,
    'post_type_b' => true
  );
  if ( ! in_array( $post->post_type, $valid_post_types ) ) {
    return;
  }
  // or with isset() <-- uses array keys
  if ( ! isset( $valid_post_types[$post->post_type] ) ) {
    return;
  }

  // Do stuff
}
```

There's also the [`save_post_{$post->post_type}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post_post-post_type/) action that you could use to directly target a certain post type save action.

```
add_action( 'save_post_my_post_type', 'prefix_my_save__cpt_post_action', 10, 3 );
function prefix_my_save_post_action( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
  // No need to check for post type as it is already in the action
  // Do stuff
}
```